# ajax post request failing after third times on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, express, mobile

I'm having a Node.js express app.

On a specific view, I have a recurrent ajax post-call, which is checking the status of a process.
On the response, if it needs to be checked again there is a timeout of 5 seconds before checking again.

It's working well on the desktop and mobile none IOS
However, as soon as I tried it on an iOS mobile it failed on the third request. (the first two worked well)

I checked different browser on the iPhone and each time is the same.

I'm having the following response from the call

```
{"readyState": 0, "status":0, "statusText": "error"}
```

It seems to be the case on every iOS devices. But it's working everywhere else (android, windows)
Any ideas where it could come from?
Very weird that it's happening working well for the first two calls and then somehow get blocked.

JS CODE OF THE REQUEST
:

```
const checkUpdate =  (amount, ref, status) => {
        $.post({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/check-update-transaction",
            data: { amount, ref, status},
            headers: {
                "CSRF-Token": token,
            },
        }).done(
            (res) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
                setTimeout(() => {
                    switch (parseInt(res.status))   {

                        case 1:
                            
                            return checkUpdate(amount, ref, 1);
                        case 2:
                            
                            return checkUpdate(amount, ref, 2);
                        case 3:
                            
                            $("#circle-loader-popup").hide();
                            return true;
                            
                    }

                }, 5000);

            }
        ).fail((error) => {
            $(".status-information .main-content-loader")
                .html(`A problem happened during the submission please try again `);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            if(error.responseJSON && error.responseJSON.notFind === true){
                $("#after-first-step").hide();
            }
        });
    };
```

Thanks in advance,

Anselme

Comment: That response means that the AJAX call has not been sent because there was an error in the JS which attempted to send it. Without seeing you JS code we can't really offer any more help than that

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks, I see the request is not being sent. Unfortunately no other errors in the logs. Also, remember that's it's only happening on iOS.. all the others platorms and android are working .. I suspect a network blockage from iOS when requests are too near but I'm not sure

Comment: Would be handy to have a live working example. Can you make a test page with some console.logs?

Comment: You can actually see it live. https://playground.cardano-native-token.com/ Fill one of the form with test data. when you confirmed submission you will see it working. The issue is happening on iOS iPhone. not on the rest.

Comment: I checked, but couldn't reproduce the issue. If you ask me, there is nothing wrong with you client side code. It is the server that replies with `{"readyState": 0, "status":0, "statusText": "error"}`, so can you post the server's code?

Comment: Hi @Klaassiek thanks for checking. Question on which os did you check? It can't come from the server. readyState 0 means the xhrRequest was not sent. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState  .. I was wondering that it could come from insufficient header sent from the first request giving bad signals to iOS Security policies but did not find any docs on this.

Comment: Hi @Klaassiek you are right... I just tried it again... and it does not do anymore.. so weird....I'm so sorry..

Answer (score 1):

Since there seems te be some confusion, reading your comments to your question, I think it would be handy to clear the confusion with this answer.

The problem with your question is, is that this response has nothing to do with the ajax request:

```
{"readyState": 0, "status":0, "statusText": "error"}
```

Here you see `readyState`, which coincidentally is also a property of the `XMLHTTPRequest` object.

So, how does the jQuery `post` method work and where does the `XMLHTTPRequest` come in?

Well, jQuery has its own implementation of the `XMLHTTPRequest` object: the jQuery XHR object, or `jqXHR`. This is the same object, but with some added functionality. It has Promise like features.

The `post` method actually returns a `jqXHR` object:

```
var thejqXHR = $.post(url);
console.log(thejqXHR.readyState); //1
```

The `readyState` here is `1`: `open() has been called.`, because `post` immediately calls `open` on the `jqXHR` object. In other words: it can never be `0`, since it is opened right away.

Since the `jqXHR` object works a like promise we can then do `done`.

```
var thejqXHR = $.post(url);
thejqXHR.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    console.log(data); //the data returned by the server
    console.log(textStatus); // always 'success'
    console.log(jqXHR.readyState);// always 4
});
```

The `done` method of the `jqXHR` object is called on success. Meaning **the request was successful**: the url is valid, the request reached the server, the server sent a valid response, of which the `data` is passed to the `done` method. And the `XHR.readySate` is 4: `The operation is complete.`

If something goes wrong, the `done` method is not called. The promise is rejected, so the `fail` method is called.

```
thejqXHR.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log(jqXHR.readyState); // always '4'
    console.log(textStatus); // always 'error'
    console.log(errorThrown); // for example 'Not Found'
});
```

Here you see, again, that the `readyState` is `4`: `The operation is complete`, the request was sent, it did not resolve for some reason, the `fail` method is called and the operation is complete (but with an error). The `errorThrown` is what you need to investigate to find our what went wrong.

To summarize: the `XHR.readyState` is pretty useless when using jQuery's `post` method. It is either `1` (`opened`) when the request has just been started, or it is '4' when the request is finished (either successfully or failed).

So, back to your line:

```
{"readyState": 0, "status":0, "statusText": "error"}
```

This has nothing to do with the `XMLHTTPRequest.readyState`. The `XMLHTTPRequest.readyState` is `4` when the request has finished. What you are dealing with here is the successful response from the server. It is the `data` that the server sends back and is passed to the success (`done`) function. In other words the request went perfectly well. The server's address was found, the server returns a valid response and it is passed back to you.

Now, why the server successfully responds with the above line, I don't know. This completely depends on the server side code that generates this line. The code you posted in your question has nothing to do with it. It is the server side code that you should investigate and find out why it returns this string with `readyState: 0`.

Hope it is a bit clearer now...

Comment: Thanks a lot Klaasiek for taking time. Ok indeed it seems some others search on the internet with similar issues led me to confusion.. So thanks for the clarification. The real issue is that posting the server code won't be productive as it's quite heavy..  The second issue is the troubleshooting, the bugs appears randomly and only on iOS (which I have only with my phone). So it's really make it difficult to debug.. Anyway I will see how I can investigate further to gather more information. And in any case, I will grant you the bounty if nothing new come! Thanks again!